# How to get javafx HostServices showDocument() to work on Android

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon-mobile

I wish to fire up the default browser on an Android phone from my app. I am using javafx and gluon. The following code outlines a recommended method using HostServices, passing HostServices to the View:

```
public class HSTest extends Application {
    private final AppManager appManager = AppManager.initialize();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // Set up host services for (main) view
        Supplier<View> mv = () -> new MainView(getHostServices());

        // And add the view
        appManager.addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, mv);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        appManager.start(primaryStage);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MainView extends View {
    public MainView(HostServices hostServices) {
        Label label = new Label("Show site page: stackoverflow");
        Button button = new Button("Fire up the site");

        // Fire up the default browser
        button.setOnAction(p -> {
            hostServices.showDocument("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        });
        
        VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, label, button);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setCenter(controls);
    }
}
```

On running the code (*gluonfx **run*** on Linux), this works as expected.  On installing to my Android phone and running *gluonfx **nativerun***, it fails with

```
java.lang.Exception: No web browser found
      at com.sun.javafx.application.HostServicesDelegate$StandaloneHostService.showDocument(HostServicesDelegate.java:152)
      at javafx.application.HostServices.showDocument(HostServices.java:115)
      :
```

*adb*, however, finds the default browser with

```
~$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

I wish to avoid using Android specific code as this is a cross-platform app and would also like to avoid using WebView because of the overhead and size where the web pages being addressed from within the app may be read only once or twice (being Ts & Cs, privacy etc.).

How then, can I get HostServices to "find" the default browser on Android?

EDIT:
Following Jose's mention of BrowserService, I create the following code:

```
    public void init() {
        // Set up services for view
        Optional<BrowserService> bs = BrowserService.create();
        if( bs.isPresent() )
        {
            Supplier<View> mv = () -> new MainView(bs.get());
            appManager.addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, mv);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Eh??");
    }
```

I get the following error with **nativerun**:

```
[Mon Feb 20 20:43:34 EET 2023][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(11049): WARNING: No new instance for interface com.gluonhq.attach.browser.BrowserService and class com.gluonhq.attach.browser.impl.AndroidBrowserService
[Mon Feb 20 20:43:34 EET 2023][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(11049): Eh??
```

SOLN:  Make sure you add the class to the attachList in the POM!

Comment: You can use Attach's [BrowserService](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/tree/master/modules/browser) for this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that.  I've been using 4.0.17-SNAPSHOT to be able to load to current Google Play and BrowserService is only in 4.0.16 I believe.  With 4.0.16 BrowserService, it does not create the BrowserService on my Android phone (12).

Comment: the snapshot should work too, if you add the Sonatype repo. But 4.0.16 should work (there are no recent changes on the service)?

Comment: Ok, tried sonatype repository, same problem.  I added an edit above to illustrate.

Comment: I take that you have the Browser dependency added to your pom, _and_ browser is added to the AttachList configuration of the GluonFX plugin?

Comment: Argh... yes apologies.  Too many open projects problem!  All good now, thanks!

Comment: I’m confused, is there an answer here?  In which case, please write an answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use BrowserService in place of HostServices making sure you add browser to the attachList of the POM.